# import mysql.connector ImportError: No module named connector

Tags: python, mysql, utilities

1) `sudo dpkg -i  mysql-connector-python_1.0.12-1ubuntu12.04_all.deb`

2) `sudo dpkg -i mysql-utilities_1.3.5-1debian6.0_all.deb`

```
(Reading database ... 50871 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace mysql-utilities 1.3.5 (using mysql-utilities_1.3.5-1debian6.0_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement mysql-utilities ...
postrm script for mysql-utilities
foundpython2.7
/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Setting up mysql-utilities (1.3.5) ...
postinst script for mysql-utilities
python2.7
found
python2.7
/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Processing triggers for man-db ...
```

(will supply parameter when it works )

3) trying to run  mysqlrplcheck:

```
$ mysqlrplcheck
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mysqlrplcheck", line 38, in <module>
    from mysql.utilities.common.server import check_hostname_alias
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/utilities/common/server.py", line 29, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named connector
```

It does not find mysql.connector. How do I configure this?

Comment: Solved the problem:  by editing  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/__init__.py
add:

from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)

Comment: Does anyone know if there an equivalent trick for Macports?

Comment: Disregard previous. For Macports, import MySQLdb not mysql.connector

Comment: You should add this as an answer rather than a comment. (This question still *appears* unanswered). Please.

Answer (score 1):

user2767144 solved the problem by editing:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/__init__.py
```

and adding:

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
path = extend_path(path, name)
```